# Creating a PDF File reader in android

Tags: android

I'm developing an application to read `PDF` Files.

So, that **my application itself has to read pdf Files. so which library is the best to show pdf files.**

I have read a dozen of related articles but I couldn't get the idea.

There is a button on the front page, by clicking that button user gets access to sdcard. all the folders are under his fingers. on opening folders if user open .pdf file , it will open other wise a toast is shown, "this is not a pdf file".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow..Dear user please don't expect SO members to do coding for your ideas..Take some effort in coding and ask SO if there are any doubts..Happy coding !!!

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to find a free and stable library. If you are opting for free try [APV PDF Viewer](https://code.google.com/p/apv/)

 Make sure you read the license if you are planning of use it.
In one of my applications where I had to display pdf files inside the app, I used [radaee pdf viewer](http://www.radaee.com/). Easy to use, deals with fonts, and maybe stable.
Problem is, it is not free. You can try it for free, but you will have a water mark in every page.
Hope this helps. Pdf in android app is not a walk in the park. I think that is the main reason that there are not tons of pdf viewers in google play. Good luck.